# Bundles for images

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, bundle

I'm just wondering, is there a way which gives you an opportunity to gather your images into a single bundle like we can do with `*.css` and `*.js` files? I've tried to find information about it, but I didn't succeed. Loading of each image in my web application takes much time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [Sprite and Image Optimization](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787) module that you could use. Here's [an article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/CSS-Sprites-and-the-ASP-NET-Sprite-and-Image-Optimization-Library.aspx) explaining in details. The idea is to put your images in the `App_Sprites` special folder and they will be combined into a single image. Then you can use them in your application with the `@Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/accept.png")` helper.

Comment: both links are broken